# Create table error?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar

I have created a new user in Oracle 10g and I want to create a table. But when I'm writing varcha2r, it will give me an error. This is what I'm writing:

```
create table aya 
(
  id number (3),
  name varchar2 (20),
);
```

When did I go wrong?

Comment: You have a common after the last column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff *comma.

Comment: For future reference: if you are posting about an issue that involves an error, you should include the actual error message that is displayed. This helps people trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table aya 
(
  id number (3),
  name varchar2 (20)--, remove , from here
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove Comma from 4th Line